# SQL Database getting deadlocked while creating Clustered Column Store Index even duing Single user Mode

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create a clustered column store index on a table with around 110 Millions of records, in past I was able to do that but now I am getting errors to do the same thing.

Below is my sql statement

```
 create clustered columnstore index ccsi on mytable
```

but I am getting below error

> Transaction (Process ID 55) was deadlocked on lock | generic waitable object resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

Even I tried putting the database to Single user mode before creating the index with no luck. I also tried to set the current transaction priority to high

```
SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY HIGH
```

But I am not sure why it is giving Deadlock issue when the database is in single user mode means no one is using the database except my query. I am using SQL Server 2014 Enterprise edition.

***Additional Details:***
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2) (KB3171021) - 12.0.5000.0 (X64)

Any suggestions will be welcome.

Comment: Can you paste dead lock graph

Comment: also paste your @@version info

Comment: Below is my version info.                                                                             Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2) (KB3171021) - 12.0.5000.0 (X64)   Jun 17 2016 19:14:09   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ).                        Sorry I don't have the trace for that query.

Comment: please enable trace and post trace

Comment: Ok Thanks, I will. As the database is on Production server and as it is Peak hours time thus I will run the trace tonight and will post that. Thanks.

Comment: No need of enabling trace,data you need is recorded in the default extended events trace ,see this answer :http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10646/31995

Comment: if you don't find them in extended events,you can use below link to enable trace flags:https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/06/capturing-deadlock-information/

Comment: Ok, I got the deadlock graph after looking at your answer in above posts, but it is too long to paste here. Thus I have shared it here. Can you please take a look at it here https://justpaste.it/z7vf

Comment: Chrome says insecure ,please paste in pastebin

Comment: If you're in single user mode, then it's quite possible the statement is experiencing intra-statement deadlocking on a parallel part. You can turn off the parallelism with `WITH (MAXDOP = 1)`, but obviously that can tank performance. A lesser setting but still higher than 1 can also help, depending on how many cores your server has.

Comment: Ok TheGameiswar, I have pasted the dead lock graph to http://pastebin.com/p4T8QGcv

Comment: Thanks Jeroen Mostert. I will try with (maxdop=1) thing out. Thanks a lot for your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen Mostert, my issue got resolved by running the query WITH (MAXDOP = 1). However it took very long time to execute, but at least now I am able complete my task.  Thank you TheGameiswar and Jeroen Mostert for your valuable suggestions.